# Proper way to specify routes on Vue Components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Coming from Angular 2/4 we would do our routes like this:

guide.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-guide',
  templateUrl: './guide.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./guide.component.scss']
})
export class GuideComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
```

guide-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'guide/:layout',
    component: GuideComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class GuideRoutingModule { }
```

guide.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    // Routing comes last
    GuideRoutingModule
```

I think that's a pretty nice way of doing it, as whatever is consuming the GuideComponent doesn't have to care what, how, or if there's a route.

In Vue, we're doing having to pass the route all the way down to the app.ts:

detail.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  template,
  name: 'Detail',
  components: {
    Something
  }
})
export class Detail extends Vue {
```

detail.route.ts:

```
export const detailRoute: RouteConfig = {
  path: '/detail/:id',
  component: Detail,
  props: (route: Route) => ({
    state: route.query.state
  })
};
```

component.routes.ts:

```
export const componentRoutes = [
  detailRoute
];
```

core.route.ts:

```
export const coreRoute = {
  path: '/',
  component: Core,
  props: (route: Route) => ({
    showPlayer: route.query.player === 'true' || !route.query.player
  }),
  children: [
    ...componentRoutes
  ]
};
```

app.ts:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [coreRoute]
});

// Bootstrap Vue app
export default new Vue({
  store,
  router,
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this? Maybe so that the component consumed the route itself and the route doesn't have to make its way down the hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Always, just give it a month and come back to your code.

> Maybe so that the component consumed the route itself and the route
>   doesn't have to make its way down the hierarchy?

I am unfamiliar with TypeScript but you can access the route from the component itself without having to pass it down the hierarchy. Here is an example in JavaScript.

## app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import store from './vuex/store'
import {router} from './router'

new Vue({
  store,
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

## router.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Detail from './components/Detail.vue'

export var router = new VueRouter({
  name: 'Router',
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/detail/:id',
      component: Detail
    }
  ]
})
```

## Detail.js

```
export default {
  name: 'Detail',
  components: {
    Something
  },
  data () {
    return {
      query: '',
      changed: false
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.query = this.$route.query 
  }
```

If you are looking to access the data globally I would look into [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) which is designed for apps with a more complex data structure.

## Edit

OK, now I understand. I found this [discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/298).  Checkout `this.$router.addRoutes()` it doesn't replace existing components but it will add them on the fly.

Comment: We're doing something like that now and I don't really like it; what I would like is to define the route on the Component, so when I bring in the Component, the route comes along with it (like Angular's modules).

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: We ended up deciding that we should stop trying to treat Vue like Angular. It doesn't have support for modules, and thus a nested application hierarchy is a lot harder to achieve. We decided Vue is more suited to a flat architecture.